# Merging shapefiles to one, rearrange columns?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, attribute-table, merge

I am trying to merge two shapefiles which both contain polygons representing properties in QGIS 2.2.

One problem is that the names of some of the columns in the attribute table differ between the two files. They contain the same information, but two of the column names are different.

I tried making two new columns in one of the files, and copied the information from the ones with the wrong names. Then I deleted the column with the wrong names.

The resault was two attribute tables with the same column names but in different order.
When I then tried merging them, I lost information in the attribute table.

What can I do differently to prevent the loss of data when merging shapefiles?

Comment: I have now tried to use the plugin 'Table manager', and it works fine to change the names of two of my columns. But, I discovered that it was one more that needed different name, but when I try to correct it through the manager it doesn't work? I saved the changes but when I reopen the attribute table it is still the old name that shows up?

Comment: I couldn't get the new column name to match the one I had in the other file, it lost a letter at the end. But, since I in the next step was going to merge these to files with seven others, I changed the names of the column in question in all of them instead. Not very practical, but now it seems to work to merge the files without problems.